# scikit learn using svm error

Tags: python, svm, scikit-learn

I am trying to use scikit-learn svm to classify emails based on the topic. However, I am unable to import the svm module from sklearn. I already have sklearn installed. The error I get is as follows:

```
>>> from sklearn import svm

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    from sklearn import svm
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .classes import SVC, NuSVC, SVR, NuSVR, OneClassSVM, LinearSVC
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\classes.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .base import BaseLibLinear, BaseSVC, BaseLibSVM
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\base.py", line 8, in <module>
    from . import libsvm, liblinear
  File "numpy.pxd", line 155, in init sklearn.svm.libsvm (sklearn\svm\libsvm.c:9096)
ValueError: numpy.dtype has the wrong size, try recompiling
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17709641/valueerror-numpy-dtype-has-the-wrong-size-try-recompiling

Answer (score 1):

As the error message seems to suggest, I would try reinstalling scikit learn.  If that doesn't work for you, you may also have to reinstall numpy/scipy.

You can use this pip command to upgrade scikit-learn to the latest version.

```
pip install -U scikit-learn
```

Comment: Thanks for your time! I have tried to do it multiple times, but i get the error: invalid commad 'egg_info'. This is happening for all scikit-learn, numpy and scipy. Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like a `sudo` issue to me.  Try `sudo pip install -U scikit-learn` and see if that helps...

Comment: You can also try `pip install --upgrade setuptools` -- you might have an old version of setuptools.

Comment: Yes I upgraded setuptools but get the same issue still. I have numpy version 1.6.2 and scipy version 0.11.0 installed.

Comment: Those are old versions of numpy and scipy -- I'd recommend upgrading to numpy 1.8.0, scipy 0.13.1, and scikit-learn 0.14.1.

Comment: Hi. thanks! I followed ur instructions and upgraded numpy, scipy and scikit-learn. however, for svm now it says 'ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.' Any ideas? The scikit-learn should have installed svm by itself right? Thanks again!

Comment: I installed numpy-MKL and it works now. Thanks for your advice before!