# pandas ValueError: numpy.dtype has the wrong size, try recompiling

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I took a new clean install of OSX 10.9.3 and installed pip, and then did

```
pip install pandas
pip install numpy
```

Both installs seemed to be perfectly happy, and ran without any errors (though there were a zillion warnings).  When I tried to run a python script with import pandas, I got the following error:

```
    numpy.dtype has the wrong size, try recompiling Traceback (most recent call last): 
    File "./moen.py", line 7, in  import pandas File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 6, in  from . import hashtable, tslib, lib 
    File "numpy.pxd", line 157, in init pandas.hashtable (pandas/hashtable.c:22331) 
    ValueError: numpy.dtype has the wrong size, try recompiling
```

How do I fix this error and get pandas to load properly?

Comment: Looks like a similar issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17709641/valueerror-numpy-dtype-has-the-wrong-size-try-recompiling

Comment: Did you figure out a way to get around this without downgrading pandas? I want to try out 0.14 version.

Comment: It looks similar, but what's unique about this question (and my current issue) is that recompiling is pointless: unlike the other question, this one explicitly clarifies that we're installing *from scratch*, and this library *still* doesn't work. The "try recompiling" output is a red herring.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can install previous version of pandas.

```
pip uninstall numpy
pip uninstall pandas
pip install pandas==0.13.1
```

In my situation it solved problem...

Comment: What worked for me is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26067692/numpy-dtype-has-the-wrong-size-try-recompiling

Answer (score 18):

```
sudo pip install pandas
sudo easy_install --upgrade numpy
```

should also realign everything.

Answer (score 5):

Uninstall both numpy and pandas and try installing pandas from source.

```
pip uninstall numpy
pip uninstall pandas
git clone git://github.com/pydata/pandas.git
cd pandas
python setup.py install
```

This worked for me and I am now able to use the latest version of pandas.

Answer (score 5):

open your python, check the imported version of your numpy.

It is very likely that you have multiple numpy installed and python always grab the old one, just make sure to delete the old one would fix the problem.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.__version__
>>> np.__file__
#if numpy version <= 1.7 would have the error
#find the file and delete it from (np.__file__)
```

then install the latest numpy if you don't have it

Comment: This was causing my problem.  When I ran `pip freeze` it printed out version 1.9.2, but when I opened up the python terminal and ran `np.__version__` it was pointing to version 1.5.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can install pandas from its git repo without having to explicitly clone it

```
pip install git+https://github.com/pydata/pandas.git
```

that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

`pip uninstall numpy` uninstalls the old version of numpy

`pip install numpy` finds and installs the latest version of numpy