# Sklearn not compatible with numpy

Tags: numpy, scikit-learn, scikits

Every time I try to use a class from `sklearn` I get the following error:

```
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .utils.fixes import signature
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .murmurhash import murmurhash3_32
  File "numpy.pxd", line 155, in init sklearn.utils.murmurhash (sklearn/utils/murmurhash.c:5029)
ValueError: numpy.dtype has the wrong size, try recompiling
```

I've tried to uninstall numpy, scikit, sklearn and reinstall it but it hasn't helped. I've OSX as an operating system. Here are the versions of the packages I'm using:

```
python 2.7.10

    numpy:          1.11.0
    pandas:         0.18.1
    scipy:          0.17.1
    scikit-learn:   0.17.1
    sklearn:        0.0 (which is weird but correct: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sklearn/)
```

Upgrading every package to the newest version doesn't work. 
Do you have any idea what I could do about this? Maybe downgrading some package?

There are a lot of questions like mine on the internet. However, none of the suggested installs/uninstalls fixed my problem. It must be something version-specific.

Comment: How did you install these packages?

Comment: Using pip. Is that all you want to know? Do you want to know more about the order? - I can't really remember. As long as there were no required packages I just installed them. Should I respect some order?

Comment: Uninstall `scikit-learn` followed by `pip install -U scikit-learn==0.16.1` and see if the issue is fixed.

Comment: No unfortunately not. I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Maybe, it's the older installation of `numpy` which is causing this to happen. You could try `print numpy.__version__` and see what is the actual version being used.

Comment: What I get is: 1.8.0rc1. What does this mean? Is it using an older version?

Comment: Unfortunately, Yes. Remedy would be to go to `../site-packages` directory and delete the numpy folder(or have a backup somewhere else) followed by `pip install numpy==1.11.0`.This should solve it.

Comment: I did that and I still get the same error and I still get the same version number for numpy. I really don't know what to do about it.

Comment: There is a similar issue faced over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26067692/numpy-dtype-has-the-wrong-size-try-recompiling/29321298#29321298

Comment: Thank you very much @NickilMaveli ! That solved the problem. Somehow everytime I imported numpy it imported the numpy of the system's python distribution (even tough I'm not using the system's python). I really can't explain why it linked to that one. However, now everything works! Thanks!

Comment: No worries. Glad you finally managed to fix it.