# import nltk does not work

Tags: python, numpy, nltk

So I just downloaded `nltk` module from the website and installed it. But when I run `import nltk` on the python console, I am getting this error. Can anybody help me? I've searched online for this error but to no avail.

```
>>> import nltk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/__init__.py", line 128, in <module>
    from nltk.chunk import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/chunk/__init__.py", line 157, in <module>
    from nltk.chunk.api import ChunkParserI
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/chunk/api.py", line 13, in <module>
    from nltk.parse import ParserI
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/parse/__init__.py", line 79, in <module>
    from nltk.parse.transitionparser import TransitionParser
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/parse/transitionparser.py", line 21, in <module>
    from sklearn.datasets import load_svmlight_file
  File "/home/jaydeep/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "/home/jaydeep/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .utils.fixes import signature
  File "/home/jaydeep/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .murmurhash import murmurhash3_32
  File "numpy.pxd", line 155, in init sklearn.utils.murmurhash (sklearn/utils/murmurhash.c:5029)
**ValueError: numpy.dtype has the wrong size, try recompiling**
```

I have tried reinstalling both `numpy` and `nltk` but I still get the same error

Comment: maybe the installed version of numpy is incompatible with your version of nltk?

Answer (score 2):

This error is typically caused when you have an older version of numpy installed.

Try by upgrading it with pip :

```
sudo pip install numpy --upgrade
```

If you have **already installed a newer numpy** and still get this, **its possible that you may have two versions of numpy** and when you access it through python-console its pointing to the older version. This is solved here : [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29321298/2142994)

Your also get this because of **openblas/atlas used by sklearn**. As per the scikit-learn advanced installation :

> using openblas can give speedups in some scikit-learn modules, but can
> freeze joblib/multiprocessing prior to openblas version 0.2.8-4, so
> using it is not recommended unless you know what you’re doing.
>
> If you
> do want to use openblas, then replacing atlas only requires a couple
> of commands. **Atlas has to be removed, otherwise numpy may not work.**

[Source](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/advanced_installation.html)

Answer (score 1):

Never mind. All I had to do was uninstall `scikit-learn` and it worked smoothly.

I don't understand why this worked. If anyone could shed some light on this it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I had the same issue in Ubuntu. Tried with upgrading numpy, uninstalled scikit-learn. Nothing works. Just restarted the system and got worked.