# I tried downloading nltk 'stopwords' using nltk.download("stopwords"), for NLP model. Which shows an error

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, nltk

I am learning Machine Learning, NLP- Natural Language Processing, where, i tried downloading nltk stopwords. I got an error as below and the code & error is like... sklearn is not defined... i have not used it in code too..

I tried installing using pip & conda using commands,
pip install --upgrade nltk (downloaded but didn't install)
conda install -c anaconda nltk (downloaded & installed but didn't work)

```
    # importing libraries
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    # importing dataset
    dataset = pd.read_csv('Restaurant_Reviews.tsv', delimiter='\t', quoting= 3)

    # Cleaning the texts
    import re
    import nltk
    nltk.download("stopwords")
    review = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', ' ', dataset['Review'][0])
    review = review.lower()

#Error! is:
NameError: name 'sklearn' is not defined

Expected is to get nltk downloaded, now the error is,

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-12f820b60d6b> in <module>()
     14 
     15 import re
---> 16 import nltk
     17 nltk.download("stopwords")
     18 review = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', ' ', dataset['Review'][0])

~\Anaconda4\lib\site-packages\nltk\__init__.py in <module>()
    126 ###########################################################
    127 
--> 128 from nltk.chunk import *
    129 from nltk.classify import *
    130 from nltk.inference import *

~\Anaconda4\lib\site-packages\nltk\chunk\__init__.py in <module>()
    155 from nltk.data import load
    156 
--> 157 from nltk.chunk.api import ChunkParserI
    158 from nltk.chunk.util import (ChunkScore, accuracy, tagstr2tree, conllstr2tree,
    159                              conlltags2tree, tree2conlltags, tree2conllstr, tree2conlltags,

~\Anaconda4\lib\site-packages\nltk\chunk\api.py in <module>()
     11 ##//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     12 
---> 13 from nltk.parse import ParserI
     14 
     15 from nltk.chunk.util import ChunkScore

~\Anaconda4\lib\site-packages\nltk\parse\__init__.py in <module>()
     77 from nltk.parse.malt import MaltParser
     78 from nltk.parse.evaluate import DependencyEvaluator
---> 79 from nltk.parse.transitionparser import TransitionParser
     80 from nltk.parse.bllip import BllipParser
     81 from nltk.parse.corenlp import CoreNLPParser, CoreNLPDependencyParser

~\Anaconda4\lib\site-packages\nltk\parse\transitionparser.py in <module>()
     19     from numpy import array
     20     from scipy import sparse
---> 21     from sklearn.datasets import load_svmlight_file
     22     from sklearn import svm
     23 except ImportError:

D:\My Data\Data Science\CurrentFocus\ML Python Workspace\Part 0 - Python All Codes & Prints\Codes_Self\sklearn.py in <module>()
      9 # =============================================================================
     10 #Preprocessing Imputer
---> 11 sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer(missing_values='NaN', strategy='mean', axis=0, verbose=0, copy=True)
     12 #Imputation transformer for completing missing values.
     13 

NameError: name 'sklearn' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not reproduce the error but if you have already installed scikit-learn, please uninstall or update it and try again. You can try upgrading numpy too.
Please refer to this question, [import nltk does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37224419/import-nltk-does-not-work)

Comment: Error was that: I have installed Python separately and again through Anaconda. Uninstalled everything and reinstalled only through Anaconda and it Worked!