# Installed georasters successfully but unable to import it

Tags: django, python-2.7, numpy, geospatial, gdal

I installed georasters using "pip install georasters".But I am unable to import it in python.The following error comes:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import georasters
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\georasters\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .georasters import get_geo_info, map_pixel, map_pixel_inv, aggregate, create_geotiff, align_rasters, \
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\georasters\georasters.py", line 37, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from pandas import hashtable, tslib, lib
  File "pandas\src\numpy.pxd", line 157, in init pandas.hashtable (pandas\hashtable.c:38509)
ValueError: numpy.dtype has the wrong size, try recompiling
```

Kindly clarify.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Numpy.dtype has the wrong size, try recompiling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26067692/numpy-dtype-has-the-wrong-size-try-recompiling)

Comment: But still after installing numpy,it gives error with fiona.