# instantiate EntityRecognizer running spacy on heroku

Tags: python, heroku, conda, spacy

Trying to run spaCy on Heroku. If I open up a REPL with `heroku run python`, I can happily `import spacy` and `nlp=spacy.load('en')`, but if I try:

```
from spacy.pipeline import EntityRecognizer
```

I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "spacy/pipeline.pyx", line 1, in init spacy.pipeline (spacy/pipeline.cpp:14821)
ValueError: spacy.syntax.parser.Parser has the wrong size, try recompiling
```

Models seem to be downloaded correctly, and I'm not building from source. So not sure where the error could be.

Comment: Which version are you using? `spacy==1.2.0`?

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling? It seems like a version clash similar to [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29321298/2883245).

Comment: thanks! yes issue was that conda was fetching an old version, pip was fetching the new one. Had to clean and reinstall a couple of times but then it worked