# why python failed to use or upgrade package installed by pip?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, path, installation

This problem may seem simple to most of you but I'm really confused. I tried to install numpy & pandas using pip. So initially I just did:

```
sudo pip install pandas.
```

It installed successfully but when i tried:`import pandas` there's error as:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
from . import hashtable, tslib, lib
File "pandas/src/numpy.pxd", line 157, in init pandas.hashtable (pandas/hashtable.c:22984)
ValueError: numpy.dtype has the wrong size, try recompiling
```

Then I assume it's the numpy version wrong (even pandas said installed a newer numpy) I tried to upgrade the numpy using "pip" but system reminded me don't have to.

As I checked, all my "pip" installed python packages are in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-package`, in which the numpy version is 1.9.1 and pandas 0.15.1

When I do `which python`, it shows me the python path`/usr/local/bin` so I assume it's using the system patron and did installed all the packages accordingly

But when I typed in "python" in console, and tried:

```
import numpy as np
np.version.version
```

It showed 1.6.1 instead of 1.9.1
Seems it never gets upgraded or failed to use the numpy installed.

How should I fix this?
Thanks

Comment: Have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24122850/pandas-valueerror-numpy-dtype-has-the-wrong-size-try-recompiling?rq=1

Comment: Yes, I tried but still failed...

Comment: Have you tried `sudo easy_install --upgrade numpy`?

Comment: btw, take a look at anaconda python distribution: https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/ It will (probably) completely eliminate problems with package installation.

Comment: @EdChum tried, said already upgrade. But the import still shows the 1.6.1

Comment: Note that it's not good to run `pip` via `sudo`. You should use `pip install --user` to install to your home directory, or use virtualenvs.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall Numpy and then Re-install the newest version of it.

```
pip uninstall numpy

pip install numpy
```

I too was facing this problem earlier.