# Blender - import pandas ImportError: No module named pandas

Tags: python, pandas, blender

when I try to run my script in Blender:

```
import bpy
import pandas as pd

datafr = pd.read_table("/Users/Admin/Desktop/Python/Programming/storage_ocp_ode.csv", delimiter = ",", index_col = 0)
...
```

I get an ImportError: No module named pandas.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/Admin/Desktop/watertank1.blend/storageobject_flow.py", line 6, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'pandas'
Error: Python script fail, look in the console for now...
```

But when I use the command line and import pandas there, it works

```
Python 3.4.3 |Anaconda 2.3.0 (x86_64)| (default, Mar  6 2015, 12:07:41) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas
>>>
```

I´m using Blender 2.76 on a Mac with OS X 10.11.

Comment: If [this answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/5289/935) doesn't help then [this answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/30517/935) gives a bit more detail. You might guess from the suggestion of looking at `sys.path` that you can add extra paths to be searched.

Comment: Thanks for your advice it worked with this:  

`sudo ln -s /Users/Admin/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas /Applications/blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.76/scripts/modules/pandas`

After this  I had to do the same with numpy, dateutil, six.py and pytz, but now it works fine!

Answer (score 3):

[Per the docs](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_76_1/info_tips_and_tricks.html#bundled-python-extensions):

> The Blender releases distributed from blender.org include a complete Python installation on all platforms, this has the disadvantage that any ***extensions you have installed in your systems Python wont be found by Blender***. (my emphasis)
>
> There are 2 ways around this:

- remove Blender Python sub-directory, Blender will then fallback on the systems Python and use that instead .. warning:

  ```
    The Python version must match the one that Blender comes with.
  ```
- copy the extensions into Blender’s Python sub-directory so Blender can access them, you could also copy the entire Python installation into Blenders sub-directory, replacing the one Blender comes with. This works as long as the Python versions match and the paths are created in the same relative locations. Doing this has the advantage that you can redistribute this bundle to others with Blender and/or the game player, including any extensions you rely on.

Comment: Thanks, I tried your first opportunity and now I have this error massage:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/Retter/Desktop/watertank1.blend/storageobject_flow.py", line 6, in <module>
File   "/Applications/blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.76/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
from pandas import hashtable, tslib, lib
File "pandas/src/numpy.pxd", line 157, in init pandas.hashtable (pandas/hashtable.c:38262)
ValueError: numpy.dtype has the wrong size, try recompiling
Error: Python script fail, look in the console for now...
@unutbu

Comment: I think it means Pandas was compiled against a newer version of NumPy than the version of NumPy installed in your blender installation. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/18369312/190597, https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/7517, http://stackoverflow.com/q/24122850/190597.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is symlinks:

```
sudo ln -s /Users/Admin/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas /Applications/blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.76/scripts/modules/pandas
```

After this I had to do the same with numpy, dateutil, six.py and pytz, but now it works fine!