# Pandas Import Error

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, versioning

I am trying to install pandas, but it throws the following error:

```
import pandas
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 7, in    
<module>
from pandas import hashtable, tslib, lib
File "pandas/src/numpy.pxd", line 157, in init pandas.hashtable 
(pandas/hashtable.c:38262)
ValueError: numpy.dtype has the wrong size, try recompiling
```

My Pandas version is 0.17.0
and my NumPy version is 1.9.2

Can Anyone help me on how to sort out the above issue?

Comment: it says the compiled module used has been compiled for a different machine, can this be the case?

Comment: Take look at these questions: [pandas ValueError: numpy.dtype has the wrong size, try recompiling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24122850/pandas-valueerror-numpy-dtype-has-the-wrong-size-try-recompiling) and [ValueError: numpy.dtype has the wrong size, try recompiling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17709641/valueerror-numpy-dtype-has-the-wrong-size-try-recompiling)

Comment: what operating system? how did you install pandas and numpy? did you get any warnings while installing numpy or pandas? if so what were they?

Comment: not a solution for the specific problem, but consider installing anaconda that could solve your problem.

Comment: I am trying all these in docker (where all packages for my project is already installed by the system's team ). I have python 2.7.10.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ValueError: numpy.dtype has the wrong size, try recompiling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17709641/valueerror-numpy-dtype-has-the-wrong-size-try-recompiling)