# ValueError: numpy.dtype has the wrong size, with import decomposition

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I'm trying to use sclearn.decomposition but i get the follwoing error:

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, Mar  9 2014, 22:15:05) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin

>>> import sklearn, numpy,scipy
>>> sklearn.__version__
'0.15.1'
>>> numpy.__version__
'1.6.2'
>>> scipy.__version__
'0.11.0'
>>> 
>>> from sklearn import decomposition
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/decomposition/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .nmf import NMF, ProjectedGradientNMF
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/decomposition/nmf.py", line 21, in <module>
    from ..utils import atleast2d_or_csr, check_random_state, check_arrays
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .murmurhash import murmurhash3_32
  File "numpy.pxd", line 155, in init sklearn.utils.murmurhash (sklearn/utils/murmurhash.c:5029)
ValueError: numpy.dtype has the wrong size, try recompiling
```

I tried un-installing and installing all the packages using pip. Not sure what else to try any suggestions?

**UPDATE:**

turns out somehow I had an old version of numpy/scipy installed I manually removed them but now I get the following runtime errors:

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scipy/stats/_continuous_distns.py:24: RuntimeWarning: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility
  from . import vonmises_cython
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scipy/stats/_continuous_distns.py:24: RuntimeWarning: numpy.ufunc size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility
  from . import vonmises_cython
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scipy/stats/stats.py:188: RuntimeWarning: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility
  from ._rank import rankdata, tiecorrect
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scipy/stats/stats.py:188: RuntimeWarning: numpy.ufunc size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility
  from ._rank import rankdata, tiecorrect
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scipy/spatial/__init__.py:90: RuntimeWarning: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility
  from .ckdtree import *
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scipy/spatial/__init__.py:90: RuntimeWarning: numpy.ufunc size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility
  from .ckdtree import *
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scipy/spatial/__init__.py:91: RuntimeWarning: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility
  from .qhull import *
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scipy/spatial/__init__.py:91: RuntimeWarning: numpy.ufunc size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility
  from .qhull import *
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/interpolate.py:28: RuntimeWarning: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility
  from . import _ppoly
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/interpolate.py:28: RuntimeWarning: numpy.ufunc size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility
  from . import _ppoly
```

Comment: Maybe it is something similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17709641/valueerror-numpy-dtype-has-the-wrong-size-try-recompiling). Otherwise you can always try installing scikit-learn from source, or use a prefabricated python environment such as anaconda.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is an issue with the binary files. I was getting the same error with pandas and I fixed it by uninstalling numpy and pandas and installing it again.

```
pip uninstall numpy
pip uninstall pandas
pip install pandas==0.13.1
```

Note that installing pandas also installs it's dependencies such as numpy.

It also seems that your versions of numpy and scipy are old. Try to update them.

Comment: As the update stated, I uninstall(some manually) and reinstalled everything using pip. these are the latest version I have installed:
>>> import numpy, scipy, sklearn, pandas
>>> numpy.__version__
'1.8.2'
>>> scipy.__version__
'0.14.0'
>>> sklearn.__version__
'0.15.1'
>>> pandas.__version__
'0.13.1'

still the same error.

the only solution is if I'm not completely uninstalling them. is there a way to check for that?

Comment: You can try locate the numpy by typing:
    import numpy
    print numpy
This is going to give you the path where numpy is located. Then all you need to do is remove the package. I hope it helps