# error installing stats models - "numpy.dtype has the wrong size"

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, pip, statsmodels

I am trying to import the statsmodels python package.  I have already installed up to date numpy and pandas packages but using the code below results in the following error.

I am running a mac with Mavericks (brand new machine), the other packages were all installed via pip installs,

```
$ pip install statsmodels --upgrade
```

Error:

```
Downloading/unpacking statsmodels
  Downloading statsmodels-0.5.0.tar.gz (5.5MB): 5.5MB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/private/var/folders/28/hc3l9sqs3z3_73h8h73wnd8w0000gn/T/pip_build_me/statsmodels/setup.py) egg_info for package statsmodels
    numpy.dtype has the wrong size, try recompiling
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/28/hc3l9sqs3z3_73h8h73wnd8w0000gn/T/pip_build_me/statsmodels/setup.py", line 463, in <module>
        check_dependency_versions(min_versions)
      File "/private/var/folders/28/hc3l9sqs3z3_73h8h73wnd8w0000gn/T/pip_build_me/statsmodels/setup.py", line 116, in check_dependency_versions
        from pandas.version import version as pversion
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
        from . import hashtable, tslib, lib
      File "numpy.pxd", line 157, in init pandas.hashtable (pandas/hashtable.c:22315)
    ValueError: numpy.dtype has the wrong size, try recompiling
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    numpy.dtype has the wrong size, try recompiling

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

  File "/private/var/folders/28/hc3l9sqs3z3_73h8h73wnd8w0000gn/T/pip_build_me/statsmodels/setup.py", line 463, in <module>

    check_dependency_versions(min_versions)

  File "/private/var/folders/28/hc3l9sqs3z3_73h8h73wnd8w0000gn/T/pip_build_me/statsmodels/setup.py", line 116, in check_dependency_versions

    from pandas.version import version as pversion

  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>

    from . import hashtable, tslib, lib

  File "numpy.pxd", line 157, in init pandas.hashtable (pandas/hashtable.c:22315)

**ValueError: numpy.dtype has the wrong size, try recompiling**

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/28/hc3l9sqs3z3_73h8h73wnd8w0000gn/T/pip_build_me/statsmodels
```

Storing debug log for failure in /Users/me/Library/Logs/pip.log

Comment: The error is in importing pandas, not in statsmodels. Check whether you really have a recent release of numpy in the python that you install in. Most of the time this is an indicator that pandas is compiled against a newer version, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17709641/valueerror-numpy-dtype-has-the-wrong-size-try-recompiling?rq=1

Comment: I used the commands below to install the most up to date versions of numpy and pandas and I am still getting the same error.

**pip install pandas==0.14.1
pip install numpy==1.8.1**

So both of those packages should be up to date now but running pip install for statsmodels still doesn't work (even if I point to the most recent statsmodels package.)

Comment: Try to import pandas in your python and see if it works. Something looks messed up in your actual versions. Check what your pip installs really did.