# sklearn "numpy.dtype has the wrong size, try recompiling" in both pycharm and terminal

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I got "numpy.dtype has the wrong size, try recompiling" in both pycharm and terminal when compiling Sci-kit learning. I've upgraded all packages(numpy, scikit to the latest), nothing works.Python version is 2.7. Please help. Appreciate!

```
    checking for nltk
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "startup.py", line 6, in <module>
    import nltk
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk/__init__.py", line 128, in <module>
      from nltk.chunk import *
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk/chunk/__init__.py", line 157, in <module>
   from nltk.chunk.api import ChunkParserI
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk/chunk/api.py", line 13, in <module>
    from nltk.parse import ParserI
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk/parse/__init__.py", line 79, in <module>
    from nltk.parse.transitionparser import TransitionParser
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk/parse/transitionparser.py", line 21, in <module>
    from sklearn.datasets import load_svmlight_file
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .utils.fixes import signature
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .murmurhash import murmurhash3_32
  File "numpy.pxd", line 155, in init sklearn.utils.murmurhash (sklearn/utils/murmurhash.c:5029)
ValueError: numpy.dtype has the wrong size, try recompiling
```

Comment: How did you install scikit and numpy?

Comment: My guess would be that you have installed sklearn through a package manager (pip? conda?) and you are using the default numpy installation of your system. It should be fixed by `pip install --upgrade scikit-learn numpy` (similar for other package managers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error "numpy.dtype has the wrong size, try recompiling" means that sklearn was compiled against a numpy more recent than the numpy version sklearn is now trying to import.   To fix this, you need to make sure that sklearn is compiled against the version of numpy that it is now importing, or an earlier version.  See [ValueError: numpy.dtype has the wrong size, try recompiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17709641/valueerror-numpy-dtype-has-the-wrong-size-try-recompiling/18369312#18369312) for a detailed explanation.

I guess from your paths that you are using the OSX system Python (the one that ships with OSX, at `/usr/bin/python`).  Apple has modified this Python in a way that makes it pick up its own version of numpy rather than any version that you install with pip etc - see https://github.com/MacPython/wiki/wiki/Which-Python#system-python-and-extra-python-packages .   I strongly recommend you switch to Python.org or homebrew Python to make it easier to work with packages depending on numpy.

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs when you are using incompatible versions. Check the versions using:

```
pip freeze
```

or, for a specific module

```
pip freeze | grep Module_Name
```

I fix my problem by updating all packages:

```
pip install -U scikit-learn numpy scipy pandas matplotlib
```

As of Today(30/11/2016). These versions are compatible:

```
matplotlib==1.5.2
nltk==3.2.1
numpy==1.11.2
pandas==0.19.1
scikit-learn==0.18.1
scipy==0.18.1
textblob==0.11.1
```