# Cannot uninstall 'numpy'

Tags: python, macos, numpy, pip, python-2.x

I've been trying to install astropy and at the end of the installation I get this message:

> Cannot uninstall 'numpy'. It is a distutils installed project and thus
> we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would
> lead to only a partial uninstall.

I have tried: `pip uninstall numpy` and then I get the same message.
I have Python 2.7.10 in a macOS High Sierra version 13.10.5

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to correctly uninstall numpy on MacOSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39187374/how-to-correctly-uninstall-numpy-on-macosx)

Comment: Take a look: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5247 : `Try removing package manually from "site-packages". This works perfect! `

Comment: @RafaelC That's linux-specific. Apple's pre-installed packages are not in site-packages, they're in a special `Extras` directory. Also, you really don't want to delete them, because they're part of the OS, and may even get reinstalled next time you run a macOS upgrade. What you need to do is trick `pip` into installing another `numpy` in front of the `Extras` one. There are multiple questions here about how to do that. (I think I even wrote the answer for the 10.11 version, but I'm not sure if it's still valid in 10.13.)

Comment: @RafaelC At any rate, it's almost always better to not use Apple's Python at all. That wasn't true from around 10.6-10.8 or 10.9, but they've fallen farther behind, non-Apple Python packaging has gotten better, and nowadays you don't usually want Python 2.7 anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but that's because you're asking the wrong question.

[Astropy requires Python 3.5 or 3.6](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/install.html). Trying to get it working with Apple's pre-installed Python 2.7 is a waste of time. You *might* be able to get an old version working this way, but not by using the installation instructions on astropy.org, and it won't be supported even if you do.

---

The easy solution is to just [Install the latest Anaconda 5.x with Python 3.6](https://www.anaconda.com/download/#macos), because it [comes with Astropy built in](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/install.html#using-conda).

---

The almost-as-easy solution is to install Python 3.6 from either a python.org binary installer, or Homebrew, and then use `pip3` or, better, `python3 -m pip` to install everything, [as explained on the Astropy install page](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/install.html#using-pip).

---

Either way, before doing anything else, you want to get back to a clean slate. In particular, you do not want `pip`, or any other scripts, attached to Apple's Python 2.7; they will only cause confusion. Assuming you can't reinstall macOS from scratch, the best way to do this is:

- Look in `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages` and delete everything there except for `README` and `Extras.pth`.
- Look in `/usr/local/bin` for symlinks to anything in that `site-packages`. (If you don't know much about using Unix, try this command: `ls -l /usr/local/bin | grep 2.7`.) You'll probably have `pip` and `pip2.7` here, and probably nothing else. But whatever you have here, delete it.

Now, when you install Python 3.6, the only thing named `pip` anywhere will be that Python 3.6's `pip`. You still want to use `pip3` or `python3 -m pip`, but if you screw up and type `pip` by accident, it won't break anything.

---

Also, you should strongly consider using a virtual environment. See the Python Packaging Authority's [User Guide](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/) (or the Anaconda docs, if you went that way) for more on this.

Answer (score 6):

One simple solution I found:

```
sudo -H pip install astropy --ignore-installed numpy
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had this issue and couldn't get around it in a clean way, but this is what I did:

Inside the Lib folder search "numpy" for an egg_info file (eg. numpy-1.11.0.dev0_2329eae.egg-info).

In my case, this is what Pip was looking at to determine if a current version already exists. I deleted it, then ran normal

```
pip install numpy
```

and installed the newest version.

I don't recommend this because I don't understand what it's doing under the hood and it doesn't properly uninstall the old version which could be a recipe for trouble down the line, but if you're desperate like I was then maybe this is a solution for you.