# Problems while importing h5py package

Tags: python, numpy, h5py

I am coding in python and trying to `import h5py`. I have installed this package before. When I try to do this, it gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/h5py/__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
  File "h5py/h5t.pxd", line 14, in init h5py._conv (/build/h5py-nQFNYZ/h5py-2.6.0/h5py/_conv.c:7359)
  File "h5py/numpy.pxd", line 66, in init h5py.h5t (/build/h5py-nQFNYZ/h5py-2.6.0/h5py/h5t.c:20505)
ValueError: numpy.dtype has the wrong size, try recompiling
```

The point is that when I `import h5py` in the directory:
`/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/` it works, but I do not have enough space there.

Does anyone know how to import this package in my data directory?
(I tried to export but it did not work!)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17709641/valueerror-numpy-dtype-has-the-wrong-size-try-recompiling does this thread not help?

Comment: Upgrade  numpy: sudo pip install --upgrade numpy

Comment: great, that is working now!

Answer (score 0):

The fact that it works in one place and not another points to a possible conflict between several installs.

I suggest that you make sure to have only one install of NumPy and of h5py.

To diagnose the problem, issue the commands

```
python -c 'import h5py; print h5py.__file__'
python -c 'import numpy; print numpy.__file__'
```

in your home directory then in `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/`, and copy the output here.

A likely solution is to

1. pip uninstall h5py
2. pip uninstall numpy

and rely on your package manager for the installation. If that is not appropriate (outdated packages, for instance), install everything with pip.