# Numpy d.type has the wrong size. Try recompiling it

Tags: python, numpy

I'm getting this error everytime i run my code . Upgraded all three libraries numpy,pandas ,sklearn. But still getting it

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
   File "machinelearning1.py", line 4, in <module>

       from sklearn import preprocessing

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/__init__.py", line 57, in <module>

       from .base import clone
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 12, in <module>

       from .utils.fixes import signature


  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>

   from .murmurhash import murmurhash3_32

  File "__init__.pxd", line 155, in init sklearn.utils.murmurhash (sklearn/utils/murmurhash.c:5620)

 ValueError: numpy.dtype has the wrong size, try recompiling. Expected 52, got 56
```

Comment: Have you looked through [this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17709641/valueerror-numpy-dtype-has-the-wrong-size-try-recompiling)

Comment: Yes. But I still get the error

Comment: you definetly need to include what versions of your packages you're using!

Comment: The versions of pandas and numpy is : 0.13.1 , 1.8.2 resp. 
I guess the problem is with installation of sklearn.The same error comes when i tried to check its version

Comment: The error comes from here: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/4d9a12d175a38f2bcb720389ad2213f71a3d7697/sklearn/utils/murmurhash.pyx#L81-L131 (well almost). Guessing you mixed up 32-bit and 64-bit versions at one point, or different architectures. How did you install the packages, and from which installation files?