# How to solve error: "numpy.dtype has the wrong size, try recompiling"

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, pyspark, virtualenv

When I execute the following statement in my code on my **Mac OS X**

```
import json, nltk, requests, time, smtplib, uuid
```

I have the followiong error:

```
18/01/22 22:03:15 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 235.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 16) on executor localhost: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException (Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 98, in main
    command = pickleSer._read_with_length(infile)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 164, in _read_with_length
    return self.loads(obj)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 422, in loads
    return pickle.loads(obj)
  File "utils.py", line 6, in <module>
    import json, nltk, requests, time, smtplib, uuid
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk/__init__.py", line 114, in <module>
    from nltk.collocations import *
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk/collocations.py", line 39, in <module>
    from nltk.metrics import ContingencyMeasures, BigramAssocMeasures, TrigramAssocMeasures
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk/metrics/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from nltk.metrics.scores import          (accuracy, precision, recall, f_measure,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk/metrics/scores.py", line 16, in <module>
    from scipy.stats.stats import betai
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/scipy/stats/__init__.py", line 324, in <module>
    from .stats import *
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/scipy/stats/stats.py", line 242, in <module>
    import scipy.special as special
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/scipy/special/__init__.py", line 531, in <module>
    from ._ufuncs import *
  File "numpy.pxd", line 155, in init scipy.special._ufuncs (scipy/special/_ufuncs.c:19983)
ValueError: numpy.dtype has the wrong size, try recompiling
```

As you can see from log, I'm using python 2,7 and pyspark (spark 1.6).

Maybe the problem is related to the fact that the software tries to use OSX system Python that use a specific version of numpy and I'm not able to understand how can avoid this.

Anyone can help me?

At this link: [ValueError: numpy.dtype has the wrong size, try recompiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17709641/valueerror-numpy-dtype-has-the-wrong-size-try-recompiling)
the problem is related to the binary distribution of packages that are compiled against a recent version of numpy.
In my case it seems that spark refer the OSX system python ("/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/scipy/stats/stats.py") instead of the "/Library/Python/2.7" i'm using in my virtual env.

Comment: SO questions are supposed to be Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  When you import modules one at a time, what happens?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ValueError: numpy.dtype has the wrong size, try recompiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17709641/valueerror-numpy-dtype-has-the-wrong-size-try-recompiling)