# ValueError: builtins.type has the wrong size, try recompiling

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, error-handling, pycharm

I have the given Python code, which I use in a venv in PyCharm.

```
from keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.applications.resnet50 import preprocess_input, decode_predictions
import numpy as np
print (np.__version__)
```

The code throws the following exception:

```
  File "type.pxd", line 9, in init mtrand
ValueError: builtins.type has the wrong size, try recompiling. Expected 840, got 864
PyDev console: starting.
Python 3.5.0a4 (v3.5.0a4:413e0e0004f4, Apr 19 2015, 18:01:47) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

I already had a look in [this similar topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17709641/valueerror-numpy-dtype-has-the-wrong-size-try-recompiling/18369312)
I upgraded everything like in the description:

```
pip install --upgrade numpy
pip install --upgrade scipy
pip install --upgrade pandas
```

And also the specific pandas version which is not needed at the point.

```
pip install pandas==0.13.1
```

Still I get the same exception. Do You have any other ideas? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: why are you using that alpha version of python though?

Comment: this is the version that worked for me using windows 10, tensorflow-gpu and keras