# numpy.ufunc has the wrong size, try recompiling.I use python3.6 under OpenBSD6.4,however,import pandas failed

Tags: python, pandas, openbsd

I installed python3.6 under OpenBSDd6.4 for data analysis(is it a good idea?)
Since  Anaconda is not working under OpenBSD, I install pip to manage python package.
I use `pkg_add -v python` to install python3.6.6

```
pip install pandas
```

the code above bring me the newest pandas version 0.23.4 and numpy 1.15.4.
when I use the `import pandas`,the wrong message comes out.

```
Python 3.6.6 (default, Oct 11 2018, 16:49:21) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible OpenBSD Clang 6.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_600/final)] on openbsd6
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from pandas._libs import (hashtable as _hashtable,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/_libs/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .tslib import iNaT, NaT, Timestamp, Timedelta, OutOfBoundsDatetime
  File "__init__.pxd", line 872, in init pandas._libs.tslib
ValueError: numpy.ufunc has the wrong size, try recompiling. Expected 112, got 124
>>>
```

I check the location and version of numpy with command,

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.__file__
'/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py'

>>> numpy.version.version
'1.15.4'
```

I google some resolution like,

```
pip uninstall pandas
pip uninstall numpy
pip install pandas -U
```

but failed.

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pandas
```

above command,failed.

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53904157/numpy-ufunc-has-the-wrong-size-try-recompiling-even-with-the-latest-pandas-and
```

above url failed.

Would you mind give me a hint on how to solve this probelms?
Is it a good choice to use OpenBSD as a data analysis platform?
Thank you.

Comment: What failure message do you get when force reinstalling Pandas? Maybe you need to delete the files from your lib after uninstalling

Comment: Thank you for you comment. pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pandas is sucessful but can not solve this problem.when import pandas,the same error appears. when I uninstall pandas and numpy, the command pip uninstall pandas and pip uninstall numpy show both package deleted from their directory,I can confirm that.

Comment: import pandas gives you the same error?

Comment: yes,the same error.

Comment: there is most likely an older version of numpy you've missed

Comment: Do you mean that some older version of numpy exists in my system? I double check /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ ,there is no numpy.And find / -name "numpy",nothing outputs.And OpenBSD do not install python2.7.5 default.Where can I find the older version of numpy?

Comment: can you open python and `import numpy`, `print(numpy)`?

Comment: >>> import numpy
>>> print(numpy)
<module 'numpy' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy-1.16.0rc2-py3.6-openbsd-6.4-i386.egg/numpy/__init__.py'>

Comment: I just easy_install numpy, a lot of warnings generated in process...I have no idea whether it stable for use.

Comment: Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas-0.23.4-py3.6-openbsd-6.4-i386.egg         I have easy_install pandas, yes, in the process I get a lot of errors and warning,but when I import pandas,there is no error message......Why?I am aware of that egg files change,openbsd in the file name.A lot of warning and error appear in the process, Does it matter?If I download the file of pandas and numpy egg file with openbsd.Can I install it by using python3.6 setup.py?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with numpy 1.14.5, I solved it with installing numpy 1.16.5

pip3.4 install numpy==1.16.5