# In Linux cluster system, ValueError: numpy.dtype has the wrong size, try recompiling. Expected 88, got 96

Tags: linux, valueerror, numpy-dtype

While trying to do simulation in the Scientific Linux, I met the following error.

```
$ python plot_distribt.py
Loaded libmkl_rt.so for dgesvd
Loaded libmkl_rt.so for zgesvd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "plot_distribt.py", line 32, in <module>
    from mps.mps import iMPS
  File "/work/wangb/DMRG/mps/mps.py", line 13, in <module>
    from algorithms.linalg import np_conserved as npc
  File "/work/wangb/DMRG/algorithms/linalg/np_conserved.py", line 294, in <module>
    from algorithms.linalg import npc_helper
  File "__init__.pxd", line 164, in init npc_helper
ValueError: numpy.dtype has the wrong size, try recompiling. Expected 88, got 96
```

After creating a virtual environment, I was able to upgrade packages via `pip2 install --upgrade numpy --user python`, and now I have numpy-1.16.6, scipy-1.2.3 and pandas-0.24.2. However, the above ValueError still occurred.

I have also checked that after opening python **within** the newly-created environment, I get

```
Python 2.7.18 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Apr 23 2020, 22:42:48)
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.version.version
'1.7.1'
>>> numpy.__file__
'/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.pyc'
>>>
```

Thus, the key might be how to avoid using the numpy-1.7.1? **Note that I cannot change anything in `/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages` as I am using the cluster systems** from our university.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ValueError: numpy.dtype has the wrong size, try recompiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17709641/valueerror-numpy-dtype-has-the-wrong-size-try-recompiling)

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your reply. I also noticed that answer before. But it did not work for me, as I was not allowed to change anything in `/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/` in our cluster system.