# Python module import error in atom editor

Tags: python, python-3.x, atom-editor

I have installed the 'script' package and launch atom editor in terminal.

I imported 'numpy' and 'pandas' like this,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
```

the autocompleting works.

When I ran it by CMD+I ,'numpy' was successfully imported but 'pandas' failed:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Dmj/Desktop/pythontest/movie_datas.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ImportError: No module named pandas
```

I can run this scrip in python3.5 shell.So I've surely installed 'pandas'.

When I import other libs it shows the same error.

How can I fix it?

OS X 10.11

Answer (score 1):

please make sure that the module `pandas` does exist in the search path `sys.path`.

```
python -c "import sys; print(sys.path);"
['', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7']
```

Comment: `python3 -c "import sys;print(sys.path);"`                                                 `['','/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python35.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/plat-darwin', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages']`                                            and the module pandas does exist in the site-packages folder

Comment: Does it mean the module is in the path? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @DomonJi Please read it. [6.1.2. The Module Search Path](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path)

Comment: @DomonJi try to install `pandas` with  `$ pip install pandas`

Answer (score 1):

just found an alternative solution for the cited problem, see
[[How to fix Python Numpy/Pandas installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12436979/how-to-fix-python-numpy-pandas-installation][1])

User sjs wrote:

> If you're like me and you don't like the idea of deleting things that
>   were part of the standard system installation (which others have
>   suggested) then you might like the solution I ended up using:
>
> Get Homebrew - it's a one-line shell script to install!
>
> Edit your `.profile`, or whatever is appropriate, and put `/usr/local/bin` at the start of your `PATH` so that Homebrew binaries are
>   found before system binaries
>
> `brew install python` - this installs a newer version of python in /usr/local
>
> `pip install pandas`
>
> This worked for me in OS X 10.8.2, and I can't see any reason it
>   shouldn't work in 10.6.8.

I had the problem that atom-runner within atom editor did not recognize pandas after installing it via pip. This is obviously a consequence of using Homebrew in combination with bash and python.

For my case, I edited `.bash_profile` and changed `PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:${PATH}"` to `PATH="/usr/local/bin/python3:${PATH}"`, and exported this path.

After, I reinstalled pandas using `pip install pandas`, and rerun the .py script that contained `import pandas as pd` without any problems in atom.